# Getting nth element from set

Tags: ti-basic

Good day,

I have a set in my program, say nums

```
{5,6,7}->nums
```

I have a for loop

```
For i,1,dim(nums)

EndFor
```

How would I get the ith element from the set? For example, print 5,6,7 from the for loop?

I've tried calling it like a function, as I've seen in many guides, but that gives an error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

:facepalm:

Somehow I didn't even try brackets. For those with the same issue, it is just

```
nums[i]
```